# Calling Quotes from data into Expression React

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a data "language":"English, Indonesian, Chinese". I want to use each Language as an expression so that I can use the SVG provided.

```
{destData.map((dest) => (
  <div
    key={dest.id}
    className=" w-48 h-80 p-2 m-2 relative flex flex-col items-center"
  >
    <img
      src={dest.imageProfile[0]?.url}
      alt={dest.name}
      className="w-full h-auto object-cover rounded-full aspect-square"
    />
    <div className="absolute top-0 right-0 flex">
      {dest.language.map((flag, index) => (
        <img
          key={index}
          src={flag}
          alt={`Flag ${index + 1}`}
          className="w-6 h-6 mr-1"
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
))};
```

images:

```
import Indonesian from "../../../assets/img/Indonesian.svg"
import UnitedStates from "../../../assets/img/UnitedStates.svg"
import Chinese from "../../../assets/img/Chinese.svg"
import Japan from "../../../assets/img/Japan.svg"
import Korea from "../../../assets/img/Korea.svg"
import Greek from "../../../assets/img/Greek.svg"
import French from "../../../assets/img/French.svg"
import English from "../../../assets/img/English.svg"
```

data:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "result": [
        {
            "id": "64e6d9f182b0d897976395b7",
            "expoPushToken": "Vk5lPR9zrX",
            "enabled": true,
            "name": "Lionel messi ",
            "surname": "Messi ",
            "idcard": "99999",
            "address": "Jakarta",
            "language": "English, Hebrew, French, Greek",
            "phone": "123123123",
            "email": "messi@gmail.com",
            "hashedPassword": "$2a$10$Vet.g5JC2zH9vGho/WOnW.se4k.sEOpzFjy8qEwfGSC2gm83c743e",
            "website": "Messi.com",
            "createdAt": "2023-08-24T04:17:53.182Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-09-04T04:01:07.529Z",
            "isLoggedIn": true,
            "imageSrc": [
                {
                    "id": "64e6d9f182b0d897976395b6",
                    "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dgbtjwctx/image/upload/v1692850633/efsw3edkopnzmgphbl4z.jpg",
                    "roomTypeId": null,
                    "hotelId": null,
                    "hotelRoomId": null,
                    "hotelRoomName": null,
                    "publicServiceId": null,
                    "menuId": null,
                    "fnbId": null,
                    "clientImageProfileId": null,
                    "clientImageId": "64e6d9f182b0d897976395b7"
                }
            ],
            "imageProfile": [
                {
                    "id": "64e6d9f082b0d897976395b5",
                    "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dgbtjwctx/image/upload/v1692850665/fffd63tiupgp0mpcfxow.jpg",
                    "roomTypeId": null,
                    "hotelId": null,
                    "hotelRoomId": null,
                    "hotelRoomName": null,
                    "publicServiceId": null,
                    "menuId": null,
                    "fnbId": null,
                    "clientImageProfileId": "64e6d9f182b0d897976395b7",
                    "clientImageId": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "64d59d7a9ab7a10c03e352fa",
            "expoPushToken": "ExponentPushToken[16su3DG_GO5_DzhNKpRVxf]",
            "enabled": true,
            "name": "Rizal Atmajaya",
            "surname": "Jokowi",
            "idcard": "777",
            "address": "Jakarta",
            "language": "English, Indonesian, Chinese",
            "phone": "123123",
            "email": "jokowi@gmail.com",
            "hashedPassword": "$2a$10$zI7HE/mBGRP72ebDuV/NteyJZBPirQF.Rl.1TiPoszQqzuwXmB2NG",
            "website": "Jokowi.com",
            "createdAt": "2023-08-11T02:31:22.254Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-09-01T02:32:52.687Z",
            "isLoggedIn": false,
            "imageSrc": [
                {
                    "id": "64d59d7a9ab7a10c03e352f9",
                    "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dgbtjwctx/image/upload/v1691721078/apwgjnzcicvx0bqqilrf.jpg",
                    "roomTypeId": null,
                    "hotelId": null,
                    "hotelRoomId": null,
                    "hotelRoomName": null,
                    "publicServiceId": null,
                    "menuId": null,
                    "fnbId": null,
                    "clientImageProfileId": null,
                    "clientImageId": "64d59d7a9ab7a10c03e352fa"
                }
            ],
            "imageProfile": [
                {
                    "id": "64d59d7a9ab7a10c03e352f8",
                    "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dgbtjwctx/image/upload/v1691721057/whbq05xaip6wucigki94.jpg",
                    "roomTypeId": null,
                    "hotelId": null,
                    "hotelRoomId": null,
                    "hotelRoomName": null,
                    "publicServiceId": null,
                    "menuId": null,
                    "fnbId": null,
                    "clientImageProfileId": "64d59d7a9ab7a10c03e352fa",
                    "clientImageId": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "message": "Successfully found all documents"
}
```

now what happens in inspect:
[image: what's happening now]

[image]

Comment: Can you create an online sandbox where we debug it?

Comment: You are not mapping your images to the language string. `dest.language` is a string from your json response and you are trying to iterate it. Even if that's an array, the string will be returned and assigned to image.